# Specific analyzers for sub-documents in lucene / elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, multilingual

After reading the documentation, testing and reading a lot of other questions here on stackoverflow:

We have documents that have titles and description in multiple languages. There are also tags that are translated to the same languages. There might be up to 30-40 different languages in the system, but probably only 3 or 4 translations for a single document.

This is the planned document structure:

```
{
 "luck": {
    "id": 10018,
    "pub": 0,
    "pr": 100002,
    "loc": {
      "lat": 42.7,
      "lon": 84.2
    },
    "t": [
      {
    "lang": "en-analyzer",
    "title": "Forest",
    "desc": "A lot of trees.",
    "tags": [
      "Wood",
      "Nature",
      "Green Mouvement"
    ]
      },
      {
    "lang": "fr-analyzer",
    "title": "Forêt",
    "desc": "A grand nombre d'arbre.",
    "tags": [
      "Bois",
      "Nature",
      "Mouvement Vert"
    ]
      }
    ],
    "dates": [
      "2014-01-01T20:00",
      "2014-06-06T20:00",
      "2014-08-08T20:00"
    ]
  }
}
```

Possible queries are "arbre" or "wood" or "forest" or "nature" combined with a date and a geo_distance filter, furthermore there will be some facets over the tags array (that obviously include counting).

We can produce any document structure that fits best for elasticsearch (or for lucene). It's crucial that each language is analyzed specifically, so we use "_analyzer" in order to distinguish the languages.

```
{
  "luck": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
    "type": "long"
      },
      "pub": {
    "type": "long"
      },
      "pr": {
    "type": "long"
      },
      "loc": {
    "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "t": {
    "_analyzer": {
      "path": "t.lang"
    },
    "properties": {
      "lang": {
        "type": "string"
      },
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "desc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A) Apparently, this idea does not work: after PUTting the mapping, we retrieve the same mapping ("GET") and it seems to ignore the specific analyzers (A test with a top-level "_analyzer" worked fine). Does "_analyzer" work for sub-documents and if yes how to should we refer to it? We also tested declaring the sub-document as "object" or "nested". How is multi-language document indexing supposed to work.

B) One possibility would be to put each language in its own document: In that case how do we manage the id? Finally both documents should refer to the same id. For example if the user searches for "nature" (and we don't know if the user intends to find "nature" in English or French), this document would appear twice in the result set, and the counting and paging would be very wrong (also facet counting).

Any ideas?